# CKEditor5 on Drupal 9 is installed and accessible via the Display Preferences but when selected there is no tool bar in the editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

both Exensions are enabled (but in different locations)
[image]

[image]

CKEditor4

[image]

CKEditor5
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have now also tried putting both versions in the core extensions folder.  Same results

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the console? Maybe also try `composer civicrm:publish` in case it needs to copy the assets from the new extension.

Comment: composer civicrm:publish  did it !!!    Is that something that is documented.  For others?  But most of all a big thanks for solving this.  Driving us crazy!!!

Comment: But now it isn't saving the contents of the editor - even when specifically requesting save draft.   any suggestions there?  Is that a known issue by chance?

Comment: I can't reproduce the not saving so not sure. Anything in ConfigAndLog?

Comment: solution to saving is here https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/ckeditor5/-/issues/6#note_69222

Answer (score 2):

Needed to run `composer civicrm:publish` to sync over some assets to the web-accessible location.

It's not currently possible I think, but in a pure composer world, you would install everything using composer, and then the asset publisher would (should) kick in by itself.